# What is the subject in the sentence “It is you who doesn’t listen” and why?

Tags: grammaticality, compound-sentences

“You *don’t* listen,” not “you *doesn’t* listen.” Why is it grammatically correct to use the singular verb phrase “does not” when it should agree with the always-plural second person pronoun “you”? Perhaps it is really, “It is you who don’t listen.”

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80493/discussion-on-question-by-nathan-m-what-is-the-subject-in-the-sentence-it-is-y).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to make several wrong assumptions here:

1. *does not* is indeed a singular verb phrase, but only for the 3rd person (*he does not listen*). In both the 1st and 2nd person you still use *don't*, as in *I don't listen* and *you (singular) don't listen*.
2. *you* is the second person pronoun as you rightly say, but **both** in the singular and the plural. The singular pronouns are *I*, *you*, *he/she/it*, the plural ones are *we*, *you*, *they*.
3. The alternative you offer is a [cleft sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence), where you move one part of the sentence to the front via an extraposed *it*. This is usually done to change the information structure, as the first element of a sentence is then in focus. It is rather unusual to do this with the subject, though, as that is already in the first position in an unmarked sentence.

So, to answer your question:

1. It is correct to say *You don't listen*, as you have a singular personal pronoun agreeing with a singular verb phrase. Both *you* and *don't* are also used in the plural, so you could equally well have a plural pronoun with a plural noun phrase (as in *You all don't listen*). *Does not* requires the third person singular.
2. The sentence *it is you who don't listen* is also wrong, as it should be *it is you who doesn't listen*. The [extraposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition) pronoun *it* becomes the subject, and as it is in the third person you then require *doesn't* instead of *don't*.